# What for is the node_modules folder that is created by running npm install create-react-app for?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, directory, node-modules

When I run `npm install create-react-app` in any folder, it creates a `node_modules` folder. What is the `node_modules` folder for? How is it related to `create-react-app`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: yes.

Long answer: `create-react-app` should be installed globally, then run inside the folder in which you wish to put your app.

Comment: If I install globally, where does the node_modules folder go?

Answer (score 3):

`create-react-app` should be installed using `npm install -g create-react-app` that will make the `create-react-app` command available in any directory.

See the [npm documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/folders#node-modules) for a complete description of the various folders that `npm` creates or writes to.

Whe you run `npm install create-react-app` (without the global (`-g`) modifier) npm executes a local dependency install and puts the results in  `./node_modules` of the current directory.

Answer (score 1):

You can install globally by `npm install -g create-react-app` if you want to avoid creating node_modules directory.

Answer (score 0):

Basically is the folder that contains all the node packages that your app requires, nmp install create-react-app depends on other node packages that will be installed in the node_modules folder.